# How to connect 2 suqueries which doesn't return single value? MySQL

Tags: mysql, member-functions

I have three tables: Player, Stats and Team.

```
**Player Table**    **Team Table**
-----------------   ----------------
id  Name     Age    id Team   Ratio
-----------------   ----------------
1  Player1   15     1  Team1    10
2  Player2   20     2  Team2    5 
3  Player3   40     3  Team3    40


**Stats Table**
-----------------------------
TName  Column    Value  A    B
-----------------------------
Player   Age     Young  10  30 
Player   Age     Mature 30  50
Player   Age     Old    50  70
Team    Ratio    Good   20  40
Team    Ratio    Medium  8  20
Team    Ratio    Bad     0   8
```

I have to write fuzzy query with some member function which will show me result who is old in this group:

```
select function(Player.age, Stats.A, Stats.B) from Player join Stats where TName = 'Player'
```

Another task is to write query which will show me who has Bad ratio:

```
select function(Team.ratio, Stats.A, Stats.B) from Team join Stats where TName = 'Team'
```

The problem is that I need to show this results on one table. I was trying subqueries `select (first_query),(second_query)` but I got error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

**EDIT**

I didn't paste here my tables but I made simpler version of that. Because of that results may not be valid:

I got:

```
**function(Player.age, Stats.A, Stats.B)**
------------------------------------------
0.22222
0.44444
1

**function(Team.ratio, Stats.A, Stats.B)**
------------------------------------------
0.52
0.1
0
```

But I want to have:

```
 |**function(Player...) | function(Team...)**|
 |   ----------------------------------------|
 |   0.22222            |    0.52            |
 |   0.44444            |    0.1             |
 |   1                  |    1               |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample of the resultset you want.

Comment: but what is the correlation between 0.22222 and 0.52 ?

Comment: can you give both subqueries a auto incrementing value? Then you can join on that.

Comment: There is no corelation. I want to create bipolar query. Which will say "find me old players and if it's possible with good ratio". I know that results from Team function may be in different order than from Player, but I wanted to make it as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer was combination of  [vahid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040506/vahid) and [verhie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223525/verhie) comments, and this is how it looks like:

```
select pl,te from
 (select function(Player.age, Stats.A, Stats.B), id from Player join Stats where TName = 'Player') as pl
 join
 (select function(Team.ratio, Stats.A, Stats.B), id from Team join Stats where TName = 'Team') as te
on pl.id = te.id
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work!

```
select * from (first_query) , (second_query)
```

Comment: Could you clarify "maybe"?

Comment: this question is ambiguous and if the results in one per table then the answer is correct.